# White Space Above Dialogue in Lollipop Device

Tags: java, android, dialog, android-alertdialog

I have one custom dialogue in my application which have not any issue. Its working fine but I am getting white space above my dialogue like this image.
[image]

I am facing issue only device which have Lollipop and lower API. My code is looking like below

```
 private void showGotoPageDialog() {
        if (getActivity() != null) {
            if (mPageOptions.length == 0)
                return;
            final Dialog mDialog = new Dialog(getActivity());
            mDialog.setContentView(R.layout.grid_dialogue);
            if(mDialog.getWindow()!=null){
            mDialog.getWindow().setLayout(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);}
            GridView mGridView = mDialog.findViewById(R.id.grid_dialog);
            ArrayList<String> tmp = new ArrayList<>(mPageOptions.length);
            for (int i = 0; i < mPageOptions.length; i++) {
                tmp.add(mPageOptions[i].split(" ")[1]);
            }
            final CustomAdapter adapter = new CustomAdapter(getActivity(), tmp, mPageIndx);
            mGridView.setAdapter(adapter);
            mGridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int item, long l) {
                    adapter.a.cancel();
                    mDialog.dismiss();
                    mPageIndx = item + 1;
                    updateQuotesList();
                    updatePageInfo();
                }
            });
            mDialog.show();
            TextView dismiss =mDialog.findViewById(R.id.dialog_dismiss);
            dismiss.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    adapter.a.cancel();
                    mDialog.dismiss();
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

Let me know if someone have idea to fix it. Thanks

Comment: what is the dialog layout? I don't see anything in your code that would matter from UI standpoint, it's layout that is important.

Comment: @M.Prokhorov Nilesh Rathod have given answer and working fine. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> White Space Above Dialogue in Lollipop Device

- it is called `Dialog` Title

Try this use **`mDialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);`** it will  remove the Blank title space from your Dialog

**Sample code**

```
final Dialog mDialog = new Dialog(getActivity());
mDialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
mDialog.setContentView(R.layout.grid_dialogue);
mDialog.getWindow().setLayout(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);}
GridView mGridView = mDialog.findViewById(R.id.grid_dialog);
// your whole dialog code
```

Comment: Thanks for nice answer. It have solved my issue. Thanks a lot :)